# Creating a spin from my installation

Tags: 12.04, custom-distributions, custom-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

Over the last 6 months or so I have tweaked & customized my Ubuntu installation until I have what I feel is a perfect Distro! Now I would like to turn it into a custom Ubuntu spin that can be run either as I live DVD/USB or installed to a users HDD. Is there an "easy" way to do this?

I would want to use the standard Ubuntu installer but the distro would have it's own name, so I may need to customize the installer to reflect this.

Comment: Whenever we close questions on the site a link to the duplicate is always present: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5523/closed-as-duplicate-of-what